# Block API call angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I have a scenario where I need to block calls to a certain function till the result of api1 has been stored in state.

Scenario:

Call api1, store result in state, retrieve the result from state and then call the below function

I have a selector that returns a Boolean observable isLoaded flag once api1 has been called and the result of api1 has been stored in the store.

I need to make the following calls only after the isLoaded flag is updated to true:

```
  private someSubject: Subject<{ skip?: boolean; defer?: number }> = new Subject<{
    skip?: boolean;
    defer?: number;   }>();    

private getData() {
    this.someSubject
      .asObservable()
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
        switchMap(({ skip, defer }) => of(skip).pipe(delay(defer))),
        switchMap(skip => {
          if (skip) {
            return this.getDataAsObservable();
          }
      
        }),
      
      )
      .subscribe();   }
```

How can I make sure the following is executed only after the isLoaded flag is set to true and after api1 has been called?

Comment: Please use only relevant tags. [tag:angularjs] is for AngularJs a legacy framework that stopped development before version 2. [tag:angular] is for Angular, a framework that continues active development.